# Using dictionary in DocumentTermMatrix in tm not working properly

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to create a Document Term Matrix using the tm package in R using a predetermined vocabulary and I am getting incorrect results. Here's the code:

```
library(tm)

a = c("good great awesome", "aww nice great")
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(a))

#no dictionary works as expected:
as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus))


#now if I want my own vocabulary:

terms = c("good", "nice", "aww", "bad", "awesome")
as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(dictionary=terms)))

#this gives: 
#Docs good nice aww bad awesome
#   1    1    1   0   0       0
#   2    0    0   1   1       0
```

which is wrong. Anyone know what is going on?

More info on the versions:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.5 (Sierra)
tm_0.7-1
```

Comment: Maybe you found a bug with the new `SimpleCorpus` object. It seems to work with `corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(a))`.